# Joining without matching all rows of 'y' using dplyr

Tags: sql, r, left-join, inner-join

The problems with the base function `merge` are well documented online yet still cause havoc. `plyr::join` solved many of these issues and works fantastically. The new kid on the block is `dplyr`. I'd like to know how to perform option 2 in the example below using `dplyr`. Anyone know if that's possible, and should it be a feature request?

## Reproducible example

```
df1 <- data.frame(nm = c("y", "x", "z"), v2 = 10:12)
df2 <- data.frame(nm = c("x", "x", "y", "z", "x"), v1 = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1))
```

### Option 1: merge

```
merge(df1, df2, by = "nm", all.x = T, all.y = F)
```

This doesn't provide what I want and messes with the order:

```
##   nm v2 v1
## 1  x 11  1
## 2  x 11  1
## 3  x 11  1
## 4  y 10  2
## 5  z 12  3
```

### Option 2: plyr - this is what I want, but it's a little slow

```
library(plyr)
join(df1, df2, match = "first")
```

Note: only rows from x are kept:

```
##   nm v2 v1
## 1  y 10  2
## 2  x 11  1
## 3  z 12  3
```

### Option 3: dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df1, df2)
```

This changes the order and keeps rows from y.

```
##   nm v2 v1
## 1  x 11  1
## 2  x 11  1
## 3  y 10  2
## 4  z 12  3
## 5  x 11  1

left_join(df1, df2)
```

The only difference here is the order:

```
##   nm v2 v1
## 1  y 10  2
## 2  x 11  1
## 3  x 11  1
## 4  x 11  1
## 5  z 12  3
```

This is a really useful feature so surprised option 2 is not even possible with dplyr, unless I've missed something.

Comment: Wouldn't `df2$v1[match(df1$nm, df2$nm)]` work?  This doesn't match all rows, just the first occurence

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are looking for is possible using `dplyr`. However, in this case you can get the desired output using the code below.

```
library(dplyr)    
unique(inner_join(df1, df2))
```

Output:

```
  nm v2 v1
1  x 11  1
3  y 10  2
4  z 12  3
```

Comment: Great thanks for the answer. Imagine an innate dplyr solution would be faster, but that one definitely works.

Comment: Only problem with this approach: it's slow!